# Words or expressions for Scribbles and Erasure

Tags: vocabulary

I've been curious about a word to express those 'marks' that we have, mostly, on pen written texts, usually when you write and make a mistake and you can't erase you have to cross out the word, then you have that "dirty mark". In my native language we have a specific word for that. I looked for the translation of the words we have and found *scribbles* and *erasure*.

So here is my question: Are the words from the title correct to refer to that? Can I get some examples? Is there any other word or expression to express this?

To see what I mean see this image:

[image: picture of scribbling out words on a page]

Comment: I would call that a *scratch-out* or, as you say, a *cross-out*. A *scribble* is a hasty and untidy writing or drawing, and an *erasure* removes the mark, entirely (more or less) - which as you point out cannot usually be achieved with inked markings.

Comment: _Crossing-out_ is the variant I remember.

Answer (score 2):

I've always called this a [*scratch*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scratch):

> **verb (used with object)**
>
> - to erase, cancel, strike out, or eliminate (a name, something written, etc.) by or as if by drawing a line through it (often followed by out  ): *Scratch out the third name on the list.*
>
> **noun**
>
> - a rough mark made by a pen, pencil, etc.; scrawl.
>
> — source: [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scratch)

This describes both the physical act of scratching out the word, as well as metaphorically erasing it from the text.

On a side note, the phrase [*chicken scratch*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/chicken+scratch) might apply if an entire body of text is so poorly written, it approaches illegibility:

> An instance of cramped or illegible handwriting

Answer (score 2):

This is often called a *cross-out* as you suggested. It also could be called a **[strikethrough](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/strikethrough)** or **strikeout**.  While these terms are more often used for printed text that has been deleted, it could be used for handwritten text.

*Erasure* would likely not be appropriate since it conveys a removing of the offending phrase rather than crossing it out.

Answer (score 2):

When the marks are handwritten, it is often referred to as "crossing outs" or "crossing offs".
If you want to express the action of marking a word or phrase as erroneous then simply say,
**to cross out** or **to cross off**.

> I'd prefer if you just cross out the wrong answer, rather than go over
>   it with Tipp-Ex/correction fluid.

To *delete*, *erase* or *rub out* a word means that the written word disappears from the page.

In Britain, pencil erasers are normally called *rubbers* (much to the bemusement of Americans), and I don't think *to rub out* is a common expression in the US nevertheless, note that the same preposition, out, is used in *[cross out](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cross+out)* and [*rub out*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rub+out).

*Scribbles* on the other hand, is often used to describe someone's awful handwriting, or when a child is learning to write. You [scribble](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/scribble) something on a note or on a list especially when you are in a hurry. Usually the only person able to decipher the message is the writer himself.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a word that applies specifically to handwritten marks. It appears that in English most words transcended into the digital era.

*Emendation* and *redaction*, though, could apply.

> **redact** to edit a text for publication. (NOAD)
>
> **emend** to make corrections and improvements to (a text). (NOAD)

*Marginalia* more specifically refers to the written marks. It less explicitly refers to revision, though. Marginalia is all notes written in the margin of the text. These could be revisions but they could just as well be a reader's comments to herself.

Answer (score 0):

I'd generally say the text is "scratched out", or maybe "crossed out" -- the latter especially if done fairly neatly, with only one or two lines.  If really obliterated, especially with ink, the resulting artifact might be called a "blot", and the text might be said to be "blotted out".